# How to retrieve all raw components of an item using Python Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, tree

I am trying to write a solution that would return a dataframe of all the `raw_components` by `item` when given the following 2 dataframes (`items` & `components`).

These two dataframes are linked by using `item_code` as the key when going from `items` to `components`. When going from `components` to `items`, `sub_component` in the `components` dataframe is used instead to relate to `item` in the `items` dataframe.

items: This dataframe holds all items that contain sub-components. An item could also be a sub-component of another item. Raw components would not exist here.

```
items = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['a', 'b'],
                   'item_code': [1, 2]
                  })
items.set_index('item',inplace = True)
```

```py
      item_code
item           
a             1
b             2
```

components : This dataframe lists the sub-components of each item in the `items` dataframe. If `sub_component` doesn't exist in the `items` dataframe (as `item`), then it is then a `raw_component` in `expected_result`.

```
components = pd.DataFrame({'item_code': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                   'sub_component': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b', 'b1'],
                    'quantity': [1, 2, 1, 1, 4]
                  })
components.set_index('item_code',inplace = True)
```

```py
          sub_component  quantity
item_code                        
1                    a1         1
1                    a2         2
1                    a3         1
1                     b         1
2                    b1         4
```

The dataframe created below is the expected output based on the current dataset.

```
expected_result = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['a','a','a','a','b'],
                   'raw_component': ['a1','a2','a3','b1','b1'],
                    'quantity': [1, 2, 1, 4, 4]
                  })
expected_result.set_index('item',inplace = True)
```

```py
     raw_component  quantity
item                        
a               a1         1
a               a2         2
a               a3         1
a               b1         4
b               b1         4
```

I tried using recursion and loops but I've been unable to figure out a solution. The challenge is that an item might have a sub-component that also has sub-components, and the number of layers is not provided.

Comment: Use `.to_clipboard` as `expected_result.to_clipboard(sep='\\s+', index=True)` instead of pasting images.

Comment: I was trying to figure out what would be the best way to display results. Thanks for the trick!